# Assigning value to member of nullable struct in C#

Tags: c#, nullable, value-type

In C#, I have a struct like this:

```
public struct Slab
{   public float[] sizeM;
    public string textureSrc;
    //more members, not relevant here...
}
```

And another like this:

```
public struct Tombstone
{   public Slab mainSlab;
    public Slab? basing;
    //more...
}
```

Now, I want to modify members of basing:

```
uiState[0].stone.basing.Value.sizeM[2] = Int32.Parse(breadthField.Value) / 100.0f;
uiState[0].stone.basing.Value.textureSrc = fileName;
```

(`uiState[0].stone` is of type `Tombstone`)

First of these two calls works correctly, as I'm just changing a member of the array in `basing`, not the array itself. However, the second complains:

```
Cannot modify the return value of 'Slab?.Value' because it is not a variable
```

It works if I do the same to `mainSlab` which is not nullable. Is there a way to do this without copying the whole `basing` to a local variable for changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without copying the whole basing to a local variable for changes?

No, because `Nullable<T>` doesn't provide direct access to the underlying value field. You can't modify it "in place".

There are all kinds of little issues like this when you use mutable structs. I'd strongly advise you to use classes or immutable structs whenever possible, to avoid these corner cases.

Comment: Probably I should, you're right. My rule of thumb is that use classes if you want polymorfism, structs otherwise, but it may be that rule is only good in D, not C#. I'll mark your answer as accepted later if you're right and someone doesn't come up with an idea.

Comment: @dukc: That's definitely not a good rule in C#. (Additionally, public fields are almost always a bad idea in C# as well, as you lose any chance of encapsulation.)  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct for more details about when to use a class and when to use a struct.

Comment: "My rule of thumb is that use classes if you want polymorfism, structs otherwise" - yeah, that's a terrible idea, and it **will** bite you; you'd be amazed how often people shoot themselves in the foot with this. Mutable structs are valid, but they are **absolutely not** synonymous with "lightweight classes, for when you don't need virtual methods"

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, the main error here is almost certainly: having a mutable struct. Now, there *are* scenarios where mutable structs make sense, but those scenarios are *narrow*, and this almost certainly isn't one of them.

Frankly, your code will be much easier to rationalize if you *stop doing that*; with recent C#, you can even use `readonly struct` to help enforce this (and to get better behaviour with `in`):

```
public readonly struct Slab
{   public readonly float[] sizeM;
    public readonly string textureSrc;
    //more members, not relevant here...
}
```

(personally I'd also consider properties instead of public fields, but that is a separate issue)

Then it becomes obvious that you can only assign the entire object:

```
Slab? foo = ...
... some logic
foo = new Slab(size, textureSource); // perhaps taking new values from the old
```

The only other alternative is *basically* to do the same thing *anyway*:

```
Slab? foo = ...
// ...
var innerVal = foo.GetValueOrDefault(); // or .Value if you've already null-checked
// ...
innerVal.textureSrc = ...
foo = innerVal;
```

Comment: Fun fact: the reason why my code is `uiState[0]` is that `uiState` is a value type too, and I needed a pointer wannabe to it. Hey, I like value semantics by default! I could do the same for `basing`, but I think I'll copy the struct this time.

Comment: @dukc are you using recent versions of C# ? "ref locals" are a thing - you can do `ref UIState x = ref uiState[0];`, which makes `x` a managed reference (technically a managed pointer); if all the `.whatever` here are fields into structs, that can *also* be used - "interior pointers". Hard to tell without full code, but you can **probably** create a `ref Slab` that is an interior pointer to `uiState[0].stone.basing` ! You cannot, however, create an interior pointer to the `Nullable<T>`'s field, because it isn't exposed; but: `ref var basing = ref uiState[0].stone.basing;`

Answer (score 0):

There may be many possible fixes for this "problem", depending on the rest of your design and requirements... For example:

```
public struct Tombstone
{
  public Slab mainSlab;
  public Slab basing;
  public bool hasBasing => basing.sizeM != null;
  //more...
}
```

To be honest I never user Nullables... Nullable value types, what's next, global rvalues?